# It is possible to use Team Foundation Service with CodePlex?

Tags: tfs, codeplex, azure-devops

I don't like limited (by default) team collaboration and agile planning features (no backlog, no board, no user stories, no iterations, etc) in the built-in CodePlex TFS version control.

Ideally, I would like to keep the project in the full featured cloud-based Team Foundation Service and directly connect it to my CodePlex project.

Is it possible? Maybe there are some tricks?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the Codeplex team has upgraded to TFS Service. Team collaboration features have not been enabled as of yet.

The current set of TFS 2012 features enabled for use are listed here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/10/02/codeplex-upgraded-to-tfs-2012.aspx

I'll check with the product team to see if there is any update to share.

Regards,
Tarun

Comment: All of these new features is the source control features, but not a planning or collaboration features. Probably in the CodePlex think that the open projects does not need anything more than the source control ... so they did not bother to remove all "unnecessary" :) 
But thanx for your answer (+1)
If you find out something - I will be glad to hear!